# How to get the thread serving the request in an asp.net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, watin, multithreading

We all know that whenever we request for a web page or hit a button(on a web page) then a new thread is created on the server to give us the required result.

Now, what I need is the thread which is serving a this request. I need to set the Apartment state of this serving thread to STA, for working with Watin API.

What I am doing is I am opening a new IE browser window on the server, the code for that I have written inside the button click event. Now Watin requires the apartment state to be STa.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide more information? "Now, what I need is the thread which is serving a this request", where do you need to retrieve this thread to? "I need to set the Apartment state of this serving thread to STA", what is the entity that is intended to set the ApartmentState and what is its relationship with the mentionned thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a new thread is not created to handle every web request.  The request is handled on a thread taken from a shared pool of available threads. Creating a new thread from scratch is pretty expensive, sometimes taking longer than the task you want to perform on the thread.

You can get the current executing thread using System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.

Since your request is executing on a shared thread managed by the IIS server, it's probably not a good idea to change the apartment model of the thread.

Answer (score 1):

[System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentthread.aspx)

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Isn't it the thread you expected? How do you decide that it isn't the correct thread?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to know anything about the server as WatiN is client-side automation.

Follow the directions here for your particular scenario: http://watin.org/documentation/sta-apartmentstate/